# Splitting 1 Zone into 2

Tags: irrigation, sprinkler-system

My front (small) and back (large) yard were put on the same zone. My front yard is in direct sunlight with little shade while my back yard is completely shaded. So watering them the same amount wastes water or my front yard dies. If I have the wires ran for 4 zones can I split the front yard from the back? Can I use one of the left over wires to add a zone to a controller if that zone start time is different?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be yes.

It's probably more complicated than wiring though. You will need to add another valve for the front yard and wire that to your controller for the new zone, find where the water line to the front splits from the line to the back and run a line from there to the new valve. If you're lucky the line splits for the two yards close to your existing valve.